# Websocket in chrome works when request is ws://localhost but fails if hosted on some IP

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I have a application from which websocket requests are established. When I host the application in my localhost all the websocket requests are successful from any browser testing in my local.

But when i host the same application on another machine and test it from my machine. Except chrome and opera all the other browsers seem to work including IE.

See the difference for the same request for Firefox and chrome

[image]

Websocket request in Firefox.
But in the chrome I get the below in the network log

[image]

[image]

As per observation i see that chrome is allowing with localhost URL. I use nginx proxy in both local and external machine

Not sure if some configuration to be made specific to browser

Comment: When the socket is on IP, is the main browser url also using the same IP?

Comment: Yes. You can see that in the screenshot that I have appended.

Comment: I can see the referrer site, i can only see the socket url

Comment: The URL on the browser is http://10.73.52.187/SelfCareAdminUI/artifacts.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved! As said it is working fine in Firefox and IE, Chrome I had to open it in no proxy mode, as i'm under my organization's proxy.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/net-dev/IhulT2eCinE