# Websocket in my chrome work only when I start in --no-proxy-server

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, websocket, proxy

I have an application that uses websockets. I'm under corporate proxy. When the application is in localhost all the websocket requests are fine in IE/Chrome and Firefox. But it works IE not in Chrome when it is hosted else where in my LAN network.

And in chrome echo from http://websocket.org/echo.html  is successful

[Websocket in chrome works when request is ws://localhost but fails if hosted on some IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093891/websocket-in-chrome-works-when-request-is-ws-localhost-but-fails-if-hosted-on/46108755#46108755)

After a long search I found http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/5245/google-chrome-how-to-assign-a-proxy-server-that-is-different-from-internet-explorers-settings/

Since then Websockets started working chrome as well.

But It is not possible for a client to start in no proxy mode.

Could anyone help me brief explanation of why it is working only in no proxy mode ? and Why it is working in IE if IE and Chrome shares same proxy settings

I'm under corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

[How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers)

Some proxies are not Websocket friendly. Try to use secure WebSockets (using `wss://` instead `ws://`), since secure connections cannot be understood by proxies.